# Reducer code for female employee by department name

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new in map-reduce coding. I request a help to write reducer code to find no. of female employees by department name.

I have two structured data files. One for employee and other for department. In the employee file I have "Empid", "Empname", "Empgender", "EmpDeptId" and "Empsalary". In the second department file I have "DepId" and "DeptName". Now I want to find out by each department name the number of FEMALE employees.

I have written one EmpMapper where I am returning the key as DeptId (IntWritable) and no. of occurrence i.e. iterations (as Text) as value. 
e.g.

```html
(1,[1])
(2,[1])
(3,[1])
(4,[1])
(1,[1])
```

and after shuffling & sorting phase the output is as below :

```html
(1,[1,1])
(2,[1])
(3,[1])
(4,[1])
```

Also from the DeptMapper I am returning the below output (key as DeptId (IntWritable) and DeptName (as Text) as value):

```html
(1,[IT])
(2,[Comsc])
(3,[Electrical])
(4,[Mechanical])
```

Now my concern is I am unable to write the reducer properly. I want to return the reducer output as

```html
(IT,2)
(Comsc,1)
(Electrical,1)
(Mechanical,1)
```

Please help me in the reducer code (where a kind of join is required).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reducer has key = IntWritable, value = Text. So you can easily join them together, but I get your issues with the types as you get the counts (e.g. "1", "1" along with the department name "IT").

An easy way would be to just check whether your text is an int, if you hit a parse error you can assume it is your department name.

Maybe below code (despite beeing hacky) might help you finding your solution:

```
@Override
protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String departmentName = null;
    int sum = 0;
    for (Text value : values) {
        String unknown = value.toString();
        try {
            int valueCount = Integer.parseInt(unknown);
            sum += valueCount;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            departmentName = unknown;
        }
    }

    assert departmentName != null;

    context.write(new Text(departmentName), new IntWritable(sum));
}
```

I don't like using exceptions for flow control, but let's be pragmatic here.

Small job improvement:

1. You can do it as a single job, by using the `MultipleInputs` classes

   1. Emit department-id as a key, count + department name as a value
   2. do the above reduce

Answer (score 0):

Writing joins in MapReduce is cumbersome. If you have structured (relational) data already it might make sense to consider a high-level framework such as [Hive](https://hive.apache.org/) that allows you to write SQL queries.

In case you want to use MapReduce for it, have a look at [this](http://codingjunkie.net/mapreduce-reduce-joins/) post for reduce-side joins and [this](http://codingjunkie.net/mapside-joins/) post for map-side joins.

Answer (score 0):

It will be basically a reduce side join, create a map of Departments in Reducer side and for every Employee get the Department of every Employee using this Map and after this main a separate data structure to count.

Comment: As per my understanding reduce task will be called 8 time for the below datasets - (1,[1,1])
(2,[1])
(3,[1])
(4,[1])
(1,[IT])
(2,[Comsc])
(3,[Electrical])
(4,[Mechanical]) so how this join will be handled here?